# Spring: json not showing repeating OneToMany entites

Tags: json, spring, hibernate

I've spent half day on it and I didn't find the answer. When I send GET request in Postman to get all my entities, it doesn't give me the repeating values. Here is my code.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SERVICE")
public class Service {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonView(View.OnlyService.class)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "SERVICE_NAME", length = 50, unique = true)
    @NotNull
    @JsonView({View.OnlyService.class, View.OnlyCategory.class})
    private String serviceName;

    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id", scope = ServerRequest.class)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @JsonView(View.OnlyService.class)
    private Category category;

    // getters and setters
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonView(View.OnlyCategory.class)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", length = 50)
    @NotNull
    @JsonView({View.OnlyService.class, View.OnlyCategory.class})
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private CategoryName name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="category", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonView(View.OnlyCategory.class)
    private List<Service> services;

    // getters and setters
}
```

and

```
@RestController
public class ServiceRestService {

    @Autowired
    ServiceRepository serviceRepository;
    @Autowired
    CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @JsonView(View.OnlyService.class)
    @RequestMapping(path = "/getAll", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Iterable<Service> getAllServices() {
        //return this.serviceRepository.findByCategoryId(1);
        return this.serviceRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

this gives a json like this

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "serviceName": "Jon's Pharmacy",
    "category": {
        "name": "PHARMACY"
    }
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "serviceName": "Adam's shop",
    "category": {
        "name": "SHOP"
    }
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "serviceName": "Judd's pharmacy",
    "category": 1
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "serviceName": "Adam's pharmacy",
    "category": 1
}
]
```

instead of

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "serviceName": "Jon's Pharmacy",
    "category": {
        "name": "PHARMACY"
    }
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "serviceName": "Adam's shop",
    "category": {
        "name": "SHOP"
    }
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "serviceName": "Judd's pharmacy",
    "category": {
        "name": "PHARMACY"
    }
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "serviceName": "Adam's pharmacy",
    "category": {
        "name": "PHARMACY"
    }
}
]
```

How to force to do it?

Forgive me all mistakes- this is my first question :)

Comment: Because you used JsonIdentityInfo, which just does that, as documented: https://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.9.0.pr4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html : *In practice this is done by serializing the first instance as full object and object identity, and other references to the object as reference values.*

Comment: Thanks. Now everything works fine :)